# How to simplify the modular congruence: $4k\equiv 4(\text{mod } 16)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

The problem arose when I was solving the two modular congruences:
$$x^2\equiv 16(\text{mod } 20)$$
$$x^2\equiv20(\text{mod }16)$$
So I put $x^2=20k+16$.
Which leads to $$20k\equiv4k\equiv4(\text{mod }16)$$
Now I want to bring the previous congruence to the form $$k \equiv \text{some number}(\text{mod }16)$$
Now how do I do that.

Edit: As directed by the answer below, I tried solving the modular congruences $x\equiv1(\text{mod }5);x\equiv2(\text{mod }4)$ and $x\equiv-1(\text{mod }5);x\equiv2(\text{mod }4)$.
I did that by setting $x=5k+1$ and then getting $x=5(4p+1)+1=20p+6$. Then in the second one, I set $x=5k-1$ and then getting $x=5(4p+3)-1=20p+14$.

So are these two solution sets correct?

Comment: The condition is equivalent to $k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$.

Comment: @Travis, Oh yes, thanks.

Comment: So is the solution set generated by: $80p+16$ correct? @Travis

Comment: Solution set to what equation?

Comment: @Travis. To both the above given modular congruences?

Comment: Are you trying to solve these two equations simultaneously?

Comment: Yes @robjohn.   .

Answer (score 1):

Your equations are
$$
\begin{align}
x^2\equiv20\pmod{16}
&\implies\frac{x^2}4\equiv1\pmod4\\
&\implies\frac x2\equiv1,3\pmod4\tag{1}
\end{align}
$$
and
$$
\begin{align}
x^2\equiv16\pmod{20}
&\implies\frac{x^2}4\equiv4\pmod5\\
&\implies\frac x2\equiv2,3\pmod5\tag{2}
\end{align}
$$

---

To solve $(1)$ and $(2)$ simultaneously, we can use the Extended Euclidean Algorithm to get
$$
1\cdot5-1\cdot4=1\tag{3}
$$
Equation $(3)$ implies $(4)$ and $(5)$
$$
\begin{align}
5&\equiv\left\{\begin{array}{}
1&\pmod4\\
0&\pmod5
\end{array}\right.\tag{4}\\
-4&\equiv\left\{\begin{array}{}
0&\pmod4\\
1&\pmod5
\end{array}\right.\tag{5}
\end{align}
$$

---

We can use $(4)$ and $(5)$ to get
$$
\color{#00A000}{1}(5)+\color{#C00000}{2}(-4)
=-3\equiv\left\{\begin{array}{}
\color{#00A000}{1}&\pmod4\\
\color{#C00000}{2}&\pmod5
\end{array}\right.\tag{6}
$$
$$
\color{#00A000}{1}(5)+\color{#C00000}{3}(-4)
=-7\equiv\left\{\begin{array}{}
\color{#00A000}{1}&\pmod4\\
\color{#C00000}{3}&\pmod5
\end{array}\right.\tag{7}
$$
$$
\color{#00A000}{3}(5)+\color{#C00000}{2}(-4)
=7\equiv\left\{\begin{array}{}
\color{#00A000}{3}&\pmod4\\
\color{#C00000}{2}&\pmod5
\end{array}\right.\tag{8}
$$
$$
\color{#00A000}{3}(5)+\color{#C00000}{3}(-4)
=3\equiv\left\{\begin{array}{}
\color{#00A000}{3}&\pmod4\\
\color{#C00000}{3}&\pmod5
\end{array}\right.\tag{9}
$$
$(6)$-$(9)$ say that $\frac x2\in\{3,7,13,17\}\mod20$. Therefore, the solution is
$$
x\in\{6,14,26,34\}\mod40\tag{10}
$$
which coincidentally, can be written as
$$
x\in\{6,14\}\mod20\tag{11}
$$

Comment: What is the solution set?

Answer (score 0):

$$x^2\equiv16\pmod{20}$$

$\implies x^2\equiv16\pmod5\equiv1\iff x\equiv\pm1\pmod5\ \ \ \ (1)$

and $x^2\equiv16\pmod4\equiv0\iff x\equiv0\pmod2$

Now $x^2\equiv20\pmod{16}\equiv4$

As $x$ must be even, $x=2y\implies4y^2=4+16k\iff y^2\equiv1\pmod4 \iff y\equiv1\pmod2$

$\implies x=2y\equiv2\pmod4\ \ \ \ (2)$

Apply CRT on $(1),(2)$

Comment: Thanks for showing the complete method, but I am a newbie at applying CRT, can you show how can we do that please?

Comment: @AdityaAgarwal, Follow http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ChineseRemainderTheorem.html

Comment: Okay, but how to do that to $\pm1$?

Comment: @AdityaAgarwal, these are two cases $\equiv1,\equiv-1$  Need to deal them separately

Comment: I am getting $x=20k+6$ or $x=20p+14$.

Comment: Is it correct? I used he same method I used above (substituting)

Comment: @AdityaAgarwal, They can be validated successfully by the given congruence equations.